# Determining coordinate system from 1981

Tags: coordinate-system

I am looking for help to determine a coordinate system used in 1981 in south east BC, Canada. The coordinate system is retrieve from some old logs, and I need to plot and find  the point locations. An example of the data is:

23, 707.3 N
14, 491.6 W

I have no idea what this coordinate system is. I need to figure out how to plot this data into UTM 11.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any registered coordinate system that matches what you describe here. Possibly it is a custom coordinate system with a custom origin or truncated values from a coordinate system. Do you know where a few of those points are located? They could be used as reference points to try and tie it to a known coordinate system. Which GIS software do you use?